# Convert multi-channel numpy array to photoshop PSD file

Tags: python, numpy, photoshop, psd

I have a numpy array with 3 RGB channels and two alpha channels. (I am using python)

I want to convert it to a Photoshop .psd file, so I can later apply transformations in photoshop on the annotated alpha layers.

I guess it a very simple task but I haven't find any way to do it from the packages I found by googling it.

I guess it should be something in the lines of the following:

```
>> im.shape
(.., .., 4)

psd = PSD()
psd.add_layers_from_numpy(im, names=["R", "G", "B", "alpha-1", "alpha-2")
with open(of, 'wb') as f:
    psd.write(f)
```

If you know how to do this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There may be a solution, but as a work-around, you might try writing a TIFF as Photoshop honours TIFF layers and pretty much treats TIFFs as near equals to PSD files. The `tifffile` and `pyvips` modules are amongst the more capable TIFF implementations - more comprehensive than **OpenCV** or **PIL**, IMHO.

Comment: I will accept anything that can be loaded to photoshop as an answer.

Comment: I have never seen an image with 2 alpha layers in Photoshop - can you share one (Dropbox or Google Drive or similar) and also show how the `Layers` window looks for such a beast please. Thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17QUzyP5MVWz1wf6efAM_XlyRm00LgTyr/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened your PSD file in Photoshop and saved it as a TIFF. I then checked with `tiffinfo` and determined that your file is saved as RGB with 3 layers of *"Extra samples"*:

```
tiffinfo MULTIPLE_ALPHA.tif

TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 1000 Image Length: 1430
  Resolution: 72, 72 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color                      <--- HERE
  Extra Samples: 3<unspecified, unspecified, unspecified>    <--- HERE
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 6
  Rows/Strip: 1430
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Software: Adobe Photoshop 21.2 (Macintosh)
  DateTime: 2020:09:08 19:34:38
```

You can load that into Python with:

```
import tifffile
import numpy as np

# Load TIFF saved by Photoshop
im = tifffile.imread('MULTIPLE_ALPHA.tif')

# Check shape
print(im.shape)           # prints (1430, 1000, 6)

# Save with 'tifffile'
tifffile.imwrite('saved.tif', im, photometric='RGB')
```

And now check that Photoshop looks at and treats the `tifffile` image the same as your original:

[image]

You may want to experiment with the `compress` parameter. I noticed your file comes out as 8.5MB uncompressed, but as 2.4MB of lossless `Zip`-compressed data if I use:

```
tifffile.imwrite('saved.tif', im, photometric='RGB', compress=1)
```

Note that reading/writing with compression requires you to install `imagecodecs`:

```
pip install imagecodecs
```

---

Note that I am not suggesting it is impossible with a `PSD`-writer package, I am just saying I believe you can get what you want with a TIFF.

**Keywords**: Image processing, Photoshop, PSD, TIFF, save multi-channel, multi-layer, multi-image, multiple alpha, tifffile, Python